# Error deleting Facebook post: OAuthExceptionMessage: (#200) This post wasn't created by the application

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page

I have a Facebook App and a Facebook place page.

I have linked the App to the page using http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=251531424968346&pages=1&page=108505012565098

I can make post from a user with location as my Facebook place. I want to delete these posts programmatically using Facebook SDK DELETE method.
The code to delete is

```
function deletepost(responseid){
        FB.api('/'+responseid, 'delete',
         function(response){
            if (response.error)
            {
            alert(response.error.message);
      });
  }
```

I tried setting resposeid as _ and

With this, i get an error "(#200) This post wasn't created by the application"

It is true that the post wasn't created by the application but being an owner of the page (and the app), can i not delete any post made on the page in any way?

Answer (score 0):

You can only delete posts

- Posted by your app, using the app access token or user access token from the user that posted them
- On the timeline of a page you're administering, using the Page access token for that page.

It sounds like you're not doing either of those - the error message is likely correct

Comment: Thanks igy for your response. I think, i am trying to do the second one. I am the admin of the page (which is a place), if a person checkins to that page, a post to my page is made and i want to delete this checkin post. Can you please give me some more details on how can i do this? I want to give it a shot. Thanks

Comment: Just to add, the post is a status with my page as a place.

Comment: Hello, I am getting this error while deleting the facebook post from java using facebook4j "This post wasn't created by the application, errorCode=200]"

Comment: And was the post you're trying to delete created by your application? If so, file a bug report with fill repro steps (including both the call to create and attempt to delete the post)