# Deleting a facebook post not created by the app (#200) This post wasn't created by the application

Tags: facebook-graph-api

A few months ago a friend asked me to clear their page of posts. I wrote a short python script that takes in their user access token, grabs their pages list, grabs the page with the matching ID, then iteratively grabs the next 25 post IDs and batches a delete call for those IDs.

A simple script. Fast forward to today, another friend asks me for the same. I grab their token, verify pages_manage_posts is set, change the page ID, and run the very same script. Instead of working perfectly, I get an error: "(#200) This post wasn't created by the application".

Right away I confirmed that the script is still using the page access token, and that the user is admin, and that the page access token has the pages_manage_posts permission. Manually constructing the call in graph explorer fails with the same error. I used the string "{PAGE_ID}_{POST_ID}?method=delete" and got the same error.

After a bit of googling [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44879892/13386708) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12885762/13386708) claim that posts can be deleted either by using the app/user token if the post was created by the app, or on the timeline of the page you're administering using the page access token. Since I was using the later as always, it should have worked.

I tried again with a different app, different account, different page, different post, different computer, different browser, and got the same error. This leads me to believe that the graph API has been updated and it's no longer possible to delete posts from pages using the API.

Is it possible to delete an arbitrary post from a page that you are admin of using v18.0 of the fb graph API? If so please provide a working example of correct syntax and permissions for the call. If not, is there confirmation from an official meta source that deleting posts from pages is no longer supported?